# Is there any way to truncate exponential matrix

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion, matrix-exponential, hermitian-matrices

The Taylor expansion of the exponential function is given by

$$
e^{-ix} = \sum_n^N \dfrac{(-ix)^n}{n!} = 1-ix -\dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \ ...
$$

suppose the $x=25$, so if I want to use the above equation to estimate

$$
e^{-25i} = \sum_n^N \dfrac{(-25i)^n}{n!}
$$

for converging I need around $100$ terms i.e. $N=100$. But if I use the following trick
$$
e^{-25i} = e^{-6 \pi i} e^{-6.15i} = e^{-6.15i}
$$
I would need a much fewer number of orders to converge $N=10$.

Now my question is whether is there any similar way to do when we have a matrix instead of a number?
$$
e^{-iA} = ?
$$
where $A$ is a matrix, in my case it is a Hermitian matrix.

I think it is difficult, but maybe someone has a good way.

Comment: You might also combine shifting with powering $e^{-iA} = (e^{iA/2^n})^{2^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $k$, we have
$$
e^{iA} = e^{i(2 \pi k I)} \cdot e^{i (A - 2 \pi k I)} = e^{i(A - 2 \pi k I)}.
$$
With that, it would suffice to select $k$ so that the eigenvalues of $A - 2 \pi k I$ are smaller in magnitude. Note that for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, $\lambda - s$ is an eigenvalue of $A - s I$.